# no such host is known. (exception from hresult: 0x80072af9) exception when running azure device client on ARM device

Tags: c#, azure, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to run Microsoft Azure device client on Raspberrypi 3 device using below piece of code. when running it in local machine it is working fine, but if I deploy to my raspberry pi 3 device it is throwing "no such host is known. (exception from hresult: 0x80072af9)"

I have windows core IOT 10 os running on my raspberry pi device and using Visual studio 2017 for this sample project. I'm able to run sample apps like helloblinky on my raspberry pi.

```
    private static DeviceClient deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create("<myiothub>.azure-devices.net", new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(<deviceid>, "<secretkey>"), Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.TransportType.Amqp);

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    receivedMessage = await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync();
                    if (receivedMessage != null)
                    {
                        messageData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedMessage.GetBytes());

                        await deviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
                        if (receivedMessage.Properties.ContainsKey("fans"))
                        {
                            GpioPinValue change = receivedMessage.Properties["fans"] == "true" ? GpioPinValue.High : GpioPinValue.Low;
                            pinValue = change;
                            pin.Write(pinValue);
                        }

                    }                 
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
```

Comment: What's kind of your app, UWP?

Comment: yes.. I have created UWP.

Comment: What's your IOT core and desktop windows versions?

Comment: I'm using windows IOT core 10 version and I have windows 10 in my lap.

Comment: What's the version number, 10.0.15063.483?

Comment: Oh.. sorry.. it is 10.0.15063.483.

Comment: And i'm not sure what I have changed, but now i'm running into below exception "System.InvalidOperationException: A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E)

Comment: Which line caused this exception?

Comment: this line receivedMessage = await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync();

Comment: How and where did you call this piece of code? Or update the code that you can reproduce the exception.

Comment: calling this on load of my application it self to receive the messages that I'm sending from rest client(postman) or [device explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer)

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Here is [a UWP sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/device/samples/UWPSample) you can reference.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll try with this sample. BTW, do we need to do any configurations on device portal before deploying app.?

Comment: Nope. Device portal is a tool that can help you monitor your device status. If it is needed you can do some configurations utilize it. More information is [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/deviceportal).

Comment: Thank you.. I have taken iotClient from that sample. Now i'm not getting any exception, but it is failing with timeout exception(at below line) while trying to receive messages. It is happening only when I run the application on device. working fine if I run in localhost.

`await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync();`

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Can you provide detailed exception information and which line cause this exception?